# add an array to an object inside an array

Tags: javascript

i have an array res and an array of object result and i want to add the res array to an key inside the object of the result array.

i'm looping to generate more than 1 object inside result array.

```
res = [{"date" : '1986/4/11',"desc":'desc'},{"date" :'2031/5/25',"desc":'desc2'}]
result = [{
            "id": data.id,
            "DBID": data.dbid,
            "date": data.date,
            "charm": data.charm,
            "defect": data.defect,
            "status": data.status,
            "summary": data.summary,
            "description": data.description,
            "actions": res
     }]
```

if i

```
console.table(result[1].actions);
```

it give me an empty array

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: `result[0].actions = res`?

Comment: `res` is not valid !!!

Comment: @kevinternet is right. the objects need valid names. `res = [{date: '1986/4/11', value: 'desc'},{date: '2031/5/25', value: 'desc2'}]`

Comment: and same problem with `result` object. You should edit with valid data

Comment: after i run the code in the actions property it give me an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Valid Data res and result
after that push in action array
result[0].actions = res;

Answer (score 0):

Oject element cannot be listed as Arrays. An object consists of

```
{key1:value1, key2:value2} instead of {value, value}
```